# node.jsでMongoDBのユニーク制約エラーのみをキャッチ

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb

TypeScriptを使っています。
以下のようにユニーク制約エラーの判定を行いたいのですが、どうすればいいのでしょうか
MongoErrorオブジェクトの型定義を見ると、message、stack、nameフィールドしかないようです。

```
try{
    await db.collection("hoge")
            .insert(foo);
}catch(e){
    if(/*eがuniqueエラーなら*/){
        //処理
    }else{
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB でユニーク制約に引っかかったかどうかの判定ですが返って来るエラーコードを確認するという方法で行っていたことがあります。

ユニーク制約であれば11000かどうかを判定すればよいかと思います。
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/8b3694d704d4c472adba87e8fb0827372324c215/src/mongo/base/error_codes.err#L237

以前使っていたときは Mongoose を使っていたと思うのですがその時は `err.code` で取れたと思います。

Answer (score -1):

Unique Indexをはることで、ユニーク制約をかけることができます。
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

具体的にどのようなエラーが発生するかは、ドライバ次第かと思われます。